# What does # mean in front of an array name in bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I read such a line:

```
arrayA=$((${#arrayB[@]}+${#arrayC[@]}));
```

What does it do? Especially what's the meaning of `#` in front of array name?

Comment: `${#a[@]}` expands to the number of elements in the array `a`. See the [_Shell Parameter Expansion_ section of the reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Thanks @gniourf_gniourf, but what is this line does in overall? I tried to run the rhs in my terminal with two arrays, and it seems to try to execute the sum result as a command? This doesn't make sense to me...

Comment: `$((...))` is the arithmetic context. `${#arrayB[@]}` and `${#arrayC[@]}` expand to the number of elements in `arrayB` and `arrayC` respectively. Hence `$((${#arrayB[@]}+${#arrayC[@]}))` expands to the sum of the number of elements in `arrayB` and `arrayC`. Check it with `echo $((${#arrayB[@]}+${#arrayC[@]}))`. Hence your snippet will assign to the variable `arrayA` the sum of the number of elements in `arrayB` and `arrayC`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf now that you've written a full answer, you may as well put it below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`${#a[@]}` expands to the number of elements in the array a. See the [Shell Parameter Expansion section of the reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

> Thanks @gniourf_gniourf, but what is this line does in overall? I tried to run the rhs in my terminal with two arrays, and it seems to try to execute the sum result as a command? This doesn't make sense to me...

- `$((...))` is the [arithmetic context](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion).
- `${#arrayB[@]}` and `${#arrayC[@]}` expand to the number of elements in `arrayB` and `arrayC` respectively.
- Hence `$((${#arrayB[@]}+${#arrayC[@]}))` expands to the sum of the number of elements in `arrayB` and `arrayC`. Check it with `echo $((${#arrayB[@]}+${#arrayC[@]}))`.
- Hence your snippet will assign to the variable `arrayA` the sum of the number of elements in `arrayB` and `arrayC`.

Demo:

```
$ arrayB=( one two three )
$ arrayC=( alpha beta gamma delta )
$ echo "${#arrayB[@]}"
3
$ echo "${#arrayC[@]}"
4
$ echo "$(( ${#arrayB[@]} + ${#arrayC[@]} ))"
7
$ arrayA=$(( ${#arrayB[@]} + ${#arrayC[@]} ))
$ echo "$arrayA"
7
```

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
arrayA=$((${#arrayB[@]}+${#arrayC[@]}));
```

Reads: `set the value of variable arrayA as the summed length of arrayB and arrayC`

`$(())` is the arithmetic expansion syntax in which you have the sum `+` of the two array lengths `${#array[@]}`